# PHP - Criar status de erro para retorno no ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Para realizar uma validação do sistema eu preciso criar um status de erro e obter este `status` no ajax em:

```
error: (function (erro) {
    //codigo 
})
```

Baseado no `http_response_code(404);` do `PHP`.

Eu consigo criar um erro `603` e obter este erro `603` no retorno do ajax ?

Eu tentei alterar/incluir o status `603` em `http_response_code("603");` mas no retorno do ajax, obtive o codigo `500`

Comment: Qual a necessidade do erro em específico? Os [códigos existentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) não lhe resolvem?

Comment: A necessidade é para tratamento interno do sistema.
Por exemplo, adicionar um devedor, sem adicionar um contrato, gera erro.
E para cada erro, existe uma mensagem especifica a ser exibida.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#114996

Comment: Eu já li sobre isso, mas não encontrei como posso incluir um status de erro

Comment: É exatamente isso que informa no link, qualquer código que não seja um erro da lista indicada, será alterado para uma reposta padrão (200 ou 500). Talvez usar a função `header` diretamente. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#107261

Comment: É isso mesmo!
Deu certo